# Fast Multiplication of matrix and vector

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, fast-fourier-transform, complex-multiplication

Multiplication of the DFT matrix and any vector can be implemented by FFT.

I'm interesting about other fast Multiplication.

Suppose there are three matrix of size $N\times N$, $F$ , $Q$ and $P$, where  $P=QFQ^T$.

$F$ is the DFT matrix and $Q$ is any orthogonal matrix.

$w$ and $x$ are two vectors of size $N\times 1$ .

If $w=Px$ (i.e., $w=[QFQ^T]x$), matrix computation need complexity of $\mathcal O(N^2)$ to obtain $w$.

Is there any way to fast implement the multiplication like FFT by complexity of $\mathcal O(N\log N)$ or other fast way?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do $Q$ have some special properties, besides being orthogonal?
If not, I am afraid that there is no simple solution to this problem. Otherwise we could take for some arbitrary matrix the singular value decomposition and could then always perform the matrix/vector multiplication in $O(n\;log\, n)$.

Comment: It can be fast implemented when $Q$ is a permutation matrix , but I don't know how to fast multiplicate for other special matrix. Besides, could you give me some concrete reference paper about fast matrix/vector multiplication by SVD. I can't grasp how can it work for arbitrary matrix. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did wrote my comment badly. I meant, that I don't think that there is a general fast way. The thing with the SVD, was more like an idea that there is no such easy solution.

Comment: sorry，I misunderstand your answer